# Error in Installing GlusterFS

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, glusterfs

I am trying to install GlusterFS on Amazon Linux ami EC2-instance. i use the below commands.

Firstly, i enable the repo:

```
[root@ip-00-00-0-000 /]# wget -P /etc/yum.repos.d https://download.gluster.org/pub/gluster/glusterfs/3.7/LATEST/EPEL.repo/glusterfs-epel.repo

[root@ip-00-00-0-000 /]# sed -i 's/$releasever/7/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/glusterfs-epel.repo
```

Then, i install with the below command:

```
[root@ip-00-00-0-000 /]# yum install -y glusterfs{-fuse,-server}
```

but i get the following error:

```
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main/latest                                                                                                                                 | 2.1 kB     00:00
amzn-updates/latest                                                                                                                              | 2.3 kB     00:00
glusterfs-epel/x86_64                                                                                                                            | 2.9 kB     00:00
glusterfs-noarch-epel                                                                                                                            | 2.9 kB     00:00
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glusterfs-fuse.x86_64 0:3.7.12-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: glusterfs-client-xlators = 3.7.12-1.el6 for package: glusterfs-fuse-3.7.12-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: glusterfs = 3.7.12-1.el6 for package: glusterfs-fuse-3.7.12-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libglusterfs.so.0()(64bit) for package: glusterfs-fuse-3.7.12-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgfxdr.so.0()(64bit) for package: glusterfs-fuse-3.7.12-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgfrpc.so.0()(64bit) for package: glusterfs-fuse-3.7.12-1.el6.x86_64
---> Package glusterfs-server.x86_64 0:3.7.12-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: glusterfs-cli = 3.7.12-1.el6 for package: glusterfs-server-3.7.12-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: glusterfs-api = 3.7.12-1.el6 for package: glusterfs-server-3.7.12-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: pyxattr for package: glusterfs-server-3.7.12-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: python-argparse for package: glusterfs-server-3.7.12-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgfapi.so.0(GFAPI_PRIVATE_3.7.0)(64bit) for package: glusterfs-server-3.7.12-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgfapi.so.0(GFAPI_PRIVATE_3.4.0)(64bit) for package: glusterfs-server-3.7.12-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgfapi.so.0(GFAPI_3.7.4)(64bit) for package: glusterfs-server-3.7.12-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgfapi.so.0(GFAPI_3.7.0)(64bit) for package: glusterfs-server-3.7.12-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgfapi.so.0(GFAPI_3.6.0)(64bit) for package: glusterfs-server-3.7.12-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgfapi.so.0(GFAPI_3.5.1)(64bit) for package: glusterfs-server-3.7.12-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgfapi.so.0(GFAPI_3.4.2)(64bit) for package: glusterfs-server-3.7.12-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgfapi.so.0(GFAPI_3.4.0)(64bit) for package: glusterfs-server-3.7.12-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: liburcu-cds.so.1()(64bit) for package: glusterfs-server-3.7.12-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: liburcu-bp.so.1()(64bit) for package: glusterfs-server-3.7.12-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgfapi.so.0()(64bit) for package: glusterfs-server-3.7.12-1.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glusterfs.x86_64 0:3.7.12-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package glusterfs-api.x86_64 0:3.7.12-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package glusterfs-cli.x86_64 0:3.7.12-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package glusterfs-client-xlators.x86_64 0:3.7.12-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package glusterfs-libs.x86_64 0:3.7.12-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package glusterfs-server.x86_64 0:3.7.12-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: liburcu-cds.so.1()(64bit) for package: glusterfs-server-3.7.12-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: liburcu-bp.so.1()(64bit) for package: glusterfs-server-3.7.12-1.el6.x86_64
---> Package python26-argparse.noarch 0:1.2.1-2.8.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python(abi) = 2.6 for package: python26-argparse-1.2.1-2.8.amzn1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: python26(dist-packages) for package: python26-argparse-1.2.1-2.8.amzn1.noarch
---> Package python26-pyxattr.x86_64 0:0.5.0-1.6.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libpython2.6.so.1.0()(64bit) for package: python26-pyxattr-0.5.0-1.6.amzn1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glusterfs-server.x86_64 0:3.7.12-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: liburcu-cds.so.1()(64bit) for package: glusterfs-server-3.7.12-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: liburcu-bp.so.1()(64bit) for package: glusterfs-server-3.7.12-1.el6.x86_64
---> Package python26.x86_64 0:2.6.9-2.84.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package python26-libs.x86_64 0:2.6.9-2.84.amzn1 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: glusterfs-server-3.7.12-1.el6.x86_64 (glusterfs-epel)
           Requires: liburcu-bp.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: glusterfs-server-3.7.12-1.el6.x86_64 (glusterfs-epel)
           Requires: liburcu-cds.so.1()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Kindly please help me resolve the issue.

```
[root@ip-00-00-0-000 /]# rpm -ivh userspace-rcu-0.7.16-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
warning: userspace-rcu-0.7.16-1.el7.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 352c64e5: NOKEY
Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]
        package userspace-rcu-0.7.16-1.el7.x86_64 is already installed
[root@ip-00-00-0-000 /]# yum install -y glusterfs{-fuse,-server}
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
http://download.gluster.org/pub/gluster/glusterfs/3.7/LATEST/EPEL.repo/epel-latest/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://download.gluster.org/pub/gluster/glusterfs/3.7/LATEST/EPEL.repo/epel-latest/noarch/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
No package glusterfs-fuse available.
No package glusterfs-server available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the stable version of glusterfs 3.6 solved the issue

```
wget -P /etc/yum.repos.d https://download.gluster.org/pub/gluster/glusterfs/3.6/LATEST/EPEL.repo/glusterfs-epel.repo

sed -i 's/$releasever/6/g' glusterfs-epel.repo
```

Answer (score 0):

Those packages are provided by the userspace-rcu (read-copy-update) package.

wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/u/userspace-rcu-0.7.16-1.el7.x86_64.rpm

rpm -ivh userspace-rcu-0.7.16-1.el7.x86_64.rpm

Comment: thanks for your comment. after i issued the command 'rpm -ivh userspace-rcu-0.7.16-1.el7.x86_64.rpm' i am getting PYCURL ERROR 22. please check the error above. any idea how to resolve this.

Comment: as i have seen above your package has been installed only the problem is with the epel URL try to install epel repo once again.
delete glusterfs-epel.repo and dowload it once again using
wget -P /etc/yum.repos.d https://download.gluster.org/pub/gluster/glusterfs/3.7/LATEST/EPEL.repo/glusterfs-epel.repo